# Extend name of group in select box when creating a new customer i admin

Tags: adminhtml, customer-group, select

When creating a new customer in admin, you are presented with a select box to select a customer group. E.g.

- A custom group
- Another custom group

I have extended the table `customer_group` to include a column for `external_id` which is imported from another source. I would like to include the value for external_id in this select box. E.g.

- A custom group (82726)
- Another custom group (23234)
- etc.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the `eav_attribute` table for the attribute `group_id` you can see the `source model` (The class that returns the options for the dropdown) is `customer/customer_attribute_source_group`.

The `getAllOptions` method uses the class `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Group_Collection` to actually get the array, so we'll rewrite that class.

In it's `config.xml` you'll need the following

```
[...]
<global>
    [...]
    <models>
        <customer_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <group_collection>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Customer_Resource_Group_Collection</group_collection>
            </rewrite>
        </customer_resource>
    </models>
    [...]
<global>
[...]
```

Now in the `Model` directory create a file with path `Customer/Resource/Group/Collection.php` with the following

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Customer_Resource_Group_Collection extends Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Group_Collection
{
    /**
     * Convert items array to array for select options
     *
     * rewritten from Varien_Data_Collection
     *
     * @param   string $valueField
     * @param   string $labelField
     * @return  array
     */
    public function toOptionArray($valueField='id', $labelField='name', $additional=array())
    {
        $res = array();

        foreach ($this as $item) {
            $res[] = array(
                'value' => $item->getData($valueField),
                'label' => "{$item->getData($labelField)} ({$item->getData('external_id')})",
            );
        }

        return $res;
    }
}
```

Which should return you a dropdown with the correct labels

Comment: This works, although in 1.8.1.0 the function is ```public function toOptionArray($valueField='id', $labelField='name', $additional=array())```

Comment: So it's not calling `_toOptionArray` in class `Varien_Data_Collection`? Thanks! didn't know that

Comment: Maybe I was a bit quick with the comment. In ```Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Group_Collection::toOptionArray``` it calls ```parent::_toOptionArray('customer_group_id', 'customer_group_code');``` which (if I'm understanding correctly) can't be overwritten at this level. Either way I had to overwrite ```public function toOptionArray``` for it to work.

Comment: Actually I think protected methods can be overwritten. But didn't test it. I'll change my answer to the public one!

Comment: Yes, protected method can be overwritten, but since it's calling ``parent:: _toOptionArray`` I dont think you can overwrite this call.